# JAVA: The input is hexadecimal numbers in string representation, for example "0xaf12". The task is to add the value of this number to the array (int)

Tags: java, parsing, integer, numbers, hex

The problem is that there is no way I can take the int value of this hexadecimal number and put it there in its hexadecimal form.
But, if I convert it to a decimal value, then all values starting from "0x8000_0000" are not parsed to int, since these values go beyond int. And if I parse through Long, then unsigned huge numbers are obtained, and I don't need such numbers - I need signed ones in the int range.

I tried to do this, and I thought it was correct since some of the examples that I checked were all correct, but the tests on the assignment show that it is not correct. But what numbers the error comes out with is not shown to me.

long b = Long.parseLong("ffffffff", 16);
System.out.println((int) (Integer.MIN_VALUE + (b - Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1)));

I also saw on the Internet that you can try somehow through bit shifts, but I did not find any use for that information for my task.

Comment: Hexadecimal routines are really somewhat broken in Java. Firstly, they are mystified by `0x` and why do they really care if 0x8000_0000 is > `Integer.MAX_VALUE`? It's a bit pattern and will fit in an `int`. You might try: `a[0] = Long.decode(s.replaceAll("_", "")).intValue();` where `s` is your hex string and `a` is your `int[]` There's justification for being mystified by `_` as it's non-standard and a visual aid for the programmer

Answer (score 0):

*then all values starting from "0x8000_0000" are not parsed to int*

Because `0x8000_0000` is `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1`. Obviously `1` more than the greatest possible `int` can't be stored in an `int`. If you need to support **arbitrary** values, use [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

```
String s = "0x8000_0000";
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(s.substring(2).replaceAll("_", ""), 16);
System.out.println(bi.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE)));
```

Outputs

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

> *And if I parse through Long, then unsigned huge numbers are obtained, and I don't need such numbers - I need signed ones in the int range.*

As @g00se said in the comments, you can use [Long.decode](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#decode(java.lang.String)) for this.  Then get the `intValue`. But first you must remove the underscore as decode will throw an exception a underscores are not permitted.

```
String[] hexValues = {"0x8000_0000", "0x8000_0001", 
        "0x1ab3", "0x10", "0x9", "0xFFFF_FFFF"};
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();

for (String hex : hexValues) {
    ints.add(Long.decode(hex.replace("_","")).intValue());
}

for (int v : ints) {
    System.out.println(v);
}
```

prints

```
-2147483648
-2147483647
6835
16
9
-1
```

You can also do it by just converting the String values to decimal imperatively using a loop. Here is how it works.  Consider `0x2AF` and starting with `2`.

```
v = 0   // initialize v
v = v * 16 + 2  (0*16) + 2 = 0 + 2
v = v * 16 + 10 (2* 16) + 10 =32 + 10 = 42
v = v * 16 + 15 (42*16) + 15 = 672 + 15 = 687
```

- first declare a string of hex digits
- the index of each is their decimal equivalent
- Converting to uppercase, repeat the previously demonstrated process.

```
String hexDigits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
for (String hex : hexValues) {
     int value = 0;
     for (char c : hex.toUpperCase().toCharArray()) {
         int index = hexDigits.indexOf(c);
         if (index >= 0) {
             value = value * 16 + index; 
         }
     }
     ints.add(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... if I parse through Long, then unsigned huge numbers are obtained, and I don't need such numbers - I need signed ones in the int range. ..."*

Parse with *Long* and just check the range before adding it.

```java
long b = Long.parseLong("ffffffff", 16);
if (b >= Integer.MIN_VALUE && b <= Integer.MAX_VALUE) {

}
```